# Appending items to a ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Checked for an hour, cannot find the answer to my question...

I'm creating a chat room app that displays `Messages` based on `TimeStamp` and `RoomID`. I'm currently using a `ListView` and calling `DataBind()` every time new messages are found. I'm using variable `List<Message> DisplayedMessages` as a data store and using `MessageList.DataSource = DisplayedMessages; MessageList.DataBind()` every time I want to display the most current messages to the user. These messages also have a `nullable` column called `ImageID` that holds a URL to a thumbnail image that is displayed directly in the `ListView`. The thing is, I'm concerned about performance issues if the user's `DisplayedMessages` were to get to a count of 5000 `Messages` with thumbnail images. That would mean that each time a new message is posted, the system would have to retrieve at least 5000 thumbnails.

I'd like to know if there is a way to simply *append* items to a `ListView` without disrupting previously added items. If that were the case, I could just add any newly found `Messages` to the user's `ListView` while leaving any already-posted `Messages` in place. I have an `UpdatePanel` in place and I'm hoping there's a way I can slap on a couple messages without having to fetch the whole data source every couple of seconds.

I like the behavior of the `ListBox` control, and was using it successfully up until the point of inserting images, having multi-line messages, and a few other problems. I find the `ListView` more flexible, but I'm willing to change controls completely if necessary. Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your list in one of these guys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Set your ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection, and then use ObservableCollection.Add() to append new messages. That should just work. You should not have to do anything else to the ListView, because ObservableCollection will notify it of any changes.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I'm working on it now, but I don't see any kind of way to set `ItemSource` of my `ListView`. Can you elaborate a little on that? Intellisense doesn't show it, but I do see references to it on the web. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the part about asp.net. Looks like DataSource is correct.